# ActiveRecord find NOT(has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a very simple model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cookies
    has_many :fortunes, :through => :cookies
end

class Cookie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :fortune
end

class Fortune < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cookies
    has_many :users, :through => :cookies
end
```

For a given user, `u`, I can do

```
u.fortunes
```

This will give me all the fortunes associated with this user via Cookies table. What I want to do is get all Fortunes not returned by `u.fortunes`.

I tried

```
Fortune.all(:limit => 5, :conditions => {:user => {:id._ne => u.id} })
```

but that doesn't work :(. I am new to ActiveRecord.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try this

```
Fortune.includes(:cookies).limit(5).where([ 'cookies.user_id != ? OR cookies.user_id IS NULL', u.id ])
```

Or with the syntax You use

```
Fortune.all(:include => :cookies, :limit => 5, :conditions => [ 'cookies.user_id != ? OR cookies.user_id IS NULL', u.id ])
```

The reason to not use include :users is to avoid one extra join.

**EDIT:**
The other suggestions are shorter, and I think also a little bit quicker when finding (no joins), I only wanted to show how to use associations.

Comment: I get: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `fortunes`.* FROM `fortunes`  WHERE (users_id != 4 OR users_id IS NULL) LIMIT 5

Comment: Sorry, it should be user_id (assuming you are following the Rails way), updated

Comment: Thanks, kinda late, but is the way you are doing it more efficient than  'u.fortunes.map(&:id)' way?

Comment: It depends. `u.fortunes.map(&:id)` is one read (with two joins), so using that will do two reads (no joins in the second). My suggestion is one read (with one join). On the other hand, if you use `u.fortunes` in the same "request" on another place in the code (doing that read anyway) then that will not cause an extra read. This only matters if your tables are big, and in that case you should add indexes on user_id in cookies (and also on fortune_id).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Fortune.limit(5).where("id not in (?)", u.fortunes.map(&:id))
```

(I tried it on my own tables)

Comment: There is not a Rails's way to do this instead of nude SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
ids_to_reject = u.fortunes.map(&:id)
Fortune.all(:limit => 5, :conditions => ["id not in (?)", ids_to_reject])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    @fortune=Fortune.find(:all).delete_if{|fortune| !fortune.user.nil? }
```

It will delete the fortunes which are belongs to user, and give us the remaining.